Factura electronica .NET error 100
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para hacer el envio que no la firma del documento dado que ya lo tengo al webservice de FACE el problema que tengo ahora es que cuando genero una firma a la petición SOAP me da un error
"100 La firma de la petición SOAP no es válida"
Me he basado en un repositorio en PHP.
Quizas estoy obviando algo que no estoy viendo
Alguien tiene conocimientos de FACE y como interactuar con esta gente?
Actualmente me devuelve un Codigo de error 100 -> La firma de la petición SOAP no es válida
Estoy usando un certificado PFX alojado en azure
Gracias de antemano.

RSA rsa;
X509Certificate certificate;
public async Task<string> GetCertificateBase64Async()
{
    string certificateName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CERTIFICATE_NAME");
    string certificateURL = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CERTIFICATE_URL");
    var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(certificateURL), new DefaultAzureCredential());

    KeyVaultCertificate certificate = await certificateClient.GetCertificateAsync(certificateName);

    var derEncodedCert = certificate.Cer;

    var x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(derEncodedCert);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(x509Cert.RawData, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
}

public async Task<X509Certificate2> DownloadCertificateAsync()
{
     string certificateName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CERTIFICATE_NAME");
     string certificateURL = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CERTIFICATE_URL");
     var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(certificateURL), new DefaultAzureCredential());

     X509Certificate2 certificateWithPrivateKey = await certificateClient.DownloadCertificateAsync(certificateName);

     return certificateWithPrivateKey;
}

public async Task<string> SendInvoiceAsync(string email, InvoiceFile invoice, List<InvoiceFile> attachments = null)
{
    var req = new StringBuilder();
    req.Append("<web:enviarFactura><request>");
    req.Append("<correo>").Append(email).Append("</correo>");
    req.Append("<factura>");
    req.Append("<factura>").Append(XmlTools.ToBase64(invoice.GetData())).Append("</factura>");
    req.Append("<nombre>").Append(invoice.GetFilename()).Append("</nombre>");
    req.Append("<mime>application/xml</mime>"); // Mandatory MIME type
    req.Append("</factura>");
    req.Append("<anexos>");
    if (attachments != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in attachments)
        {
            req.Append("<anexo>");
            req.Append("<anexo>").Append(XmlTools.ToBase64(file.GetData())).Append("</anexo>");
            req.Append("<nombre>").Append(file.GetFilename()).Append("</nombre>");
            req.Append("<mime>").Append(file.GetMimeType()).Append("</mime>");
            req.Append("</anexo>");
        }
    }
    req.Append("</anexos>");
    req.Append("</request></web:enviarFactura>");
    return await RequestAsync(req.ToString());
}
private async Task<string> RequestAsync(string body)
{
    var bodyId = "BodyId-" + RandomId();
    var certId = "CertId-" + RandomId();
    var keyId = "KeyId-" + RandomId();
    var strId = "SecTokId-" + RandomId();
    var timestampId = "TimestampId-" + RandomId();
    var sigId = "SignatureId-" + RandomId();


    var ns = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "xmlns:soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" },
        { "xmlns:web", "https://webservice.face.gob.es" },
        { "xmlns:ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" },
        { "xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" },
        { "xmlns:wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" }
    };

    // Generate request body
    var reqBody = $"<soapenv:Body wsu:Id=\"{bodyId}\">{body}</soapenv:Body>";
    var reqBodyWithNamespaces = InjectNamespaces(reqBody, ns);
    var bodyDigest = GetDigest(reqBodyWithNamespaces);

    // Generate timestamp
    var timeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var timeExpires = timeCreated.AddSeconds(REQUEST_EXPIRATION);
    var reqTimestamp = $"<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id=\"{timestampId}\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
                       $"<wsu:Created>{timeCreated:O}</wsu:Created>" +
                       $"<wsu:Expires>{timeExpires:O}</wsu:Expires>" +
                       $"</wsu:Timestamp>";
    var reqTimestampWithNamespaces = InjectNamespaces(reqTimestamp, ns);
    var timestampDigest = GetDigest(reqTimestampWithNamespaces);

    // Generate request header
    var reqHeader = new StringBuilder();
    reqHeader.Append("<soapenv:Header>");
    reqHeader.Append("<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">");
    reqHeader.Append("<wsse:BinarySecurityToken " +
        "EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\" " +
        $"wsu:Id=\"{certId}\" " +
        "ValueType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3\">" +
        XmlTools.GetCert(certificateBase64, false) +
        "</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>");

    // Generate signed info
    var c14nNamespace = useExcC14n ? "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" : "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315";
    var signedInfoNs = useExcC14n ? new Dictionary<string, string> { { "xmlns:ds", ns["xmlns:ds"] } } : ns;
    var signedInfo = new StringBuilder();
    signedInfo.Append("<ds:SignedInfo>");
    signedInfo.Append($"<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"{c14nNamespace}\"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>");
    signedInfo.Append("<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512\"></ds:SignatureMethod>");
    signedInfo.Append($"<ds:Reference URI=\"#{timestampId}\">");
    signedInfo.Append("<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512\"></ds:DigestMethod>");
    signedInfo.Append($"<ds:DigestValue>{timestampDigest}</ds:DigestValue>");
    signedInfo.Append("</ds:Reference>");
    signedInfo.Append($"<ds:Reference URI=\"#{bodyId}\">");
    signedInfo.Append("<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512\"></ds:DigestMethod>");
    signedInfo.Append($"<ds:DigestValue>{bodyDigest}</ds:DigestValue>");
    signedInfo.Append("</ds:Reference>");
    signedInfo.Append("</ds:SignedInfo>");

    // Convert StringBuilder to string
    var signedInfoString = signedInfo.ToString();


    // Inject namespaces into the signed info
    var signedInfoPayload = InjectNamespaces(signedInfoString, signedInfoNs);

    // Add signature and KeyInfo to header
    reqHeader.Append($"<ds:Signature Id=\"{sigId}\" xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">");
    reqHeader.Append(signedInfoString);
    reqHeader.Append("<ds:SignatureValue>");
    reqHeader.Append(GetSignature(signedInfoPayload));
    reqHeader.Append("</ds:SignatureValue>");
    reqHeader.Append($"<ds:KeyInfo Id=\"{keyId}\">");
    reqHeader.Append($"<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id=\"{strId}\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">");
    reqHeader.Append($"<wsse:Reference URI=\"#{certId}\" ");
    reqHeader.Append("ValueType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3\">");
    reqHeader.Append("</wsse:Reference>");
    reqHeader.Append("</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>");
    reqHeader.Append("</ds:KeyInfo>");
    reqHeader.Append("</ds:Signature>");

    // Add timestamp and close header
    reqHeader.Append(reqTimestamp);
    reqHeader.Append("</wsse:Security>");
    reqHeader.Append("</soapenv:Header>");

    // Generate final request
    var req = $"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">{reqHeader}{reqBody}</soapenv:Envelope>";
    req = InjectNamespaces(req, ns);
    req = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n{req}";

    // Extract SOAP action from "<web:ACTION></web:ACTION>"
    var soapAction = body.Substring(5, body.IndexOf('>') - 5);
    soapAction = $"{GetWebNamespace()}#{soapAction}";

    // Send request
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new StringContent(req, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        content.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        var url = GetEndpointUrl();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return res.ToString();
    }
}
public string RandomId(int length = 8)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}


public string InjectNamespaces(string xml, Dictionary<string, string> namespaces)
{
    // Split the XML into two parts: the element name and the rest of the XML
    var parts = xml.Split(new[] { '>' }, 2);
    var elementName = parts[0].Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2)[0];

    // Include missing previous namespaces and attributes
    var matches = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\s([0-9a-z:]+)=[\""'](.+?)[\""']", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in regex.Matches(parts[0]))
    {
        matches.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value));
    }
    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        if (!namespaces.ContainsKey(match.Key))
        {
            namespaces[match.Key] = match.Value;
        }
    }
    namespaces = namespaces.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

    // Prepare new XML element parts
    var xmlns = new List<string>();
    var attributes = new List<string>();
    foreach (var ns in namespaces)
    {
        if (ns.Key.StartsWith("xmlns:"))
        {
            xmlns.Add($"{ns.Key}=\"{ns.Value}\"");
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.Add($"{ns.Key}=\"{ns.Value}\"");
        }
    }

    // Generate new XML element
    var newElement = $"{elementName} {string.Join(" ", xmlns.Concat(attributes))}>{parts[1]}";
    return newElement;
}


public string GetDigest(string xml)
{
    using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
}

public string GetSignature(string payload)
{
    // Load the private key from the PEM string
    // Sign the payload using the private key and SHA-512 algorithm
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    byte[] signedBytes = rsa.SignData(dataBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    string base64Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedBytes);

    // Return the Base64 signature, optionally formatted for readability
    return base64Signature;
}

